# anyone know how to initialize an empty array

Tags: c++

Anyone know how to Initialise the array of car registration structures by placing a “Empty” in the car registration number of each array element.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct car;
    {
        string car_reg = 0;



        char car_manuf[30];
        char car_model[30];
        double price;

        string car_reg{};
    }

    
}
```

need some h3elp

Comment: a way to do that is #define EMPTY  -1 and then assign EMPTY to the car numbers in your array

Comment: In C++ why are you mixing `std::string` and C strings? If you use `std::string` this is not a problem.

Comment: @AmineDakhli I think this means the literal string `"Empty"` and not a number.

Comment: @WilliamMartens Many mistakes. Hard to isolate the true cause of the asker's problems.

Comment: @user4581301 Right, I thought it would be nice to at least say why - (as you did now, which I say thank you to) then we know what he needs to change/edit in his post! :)

Comment: @WilliamMartens Good point. Instead of trying to clean up the question I decided to write an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Explanation inline.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct car // removed ; the ; terminates the definition, cutting it off
               // and leaving you with a declaration. Everything in the braces
               // that follow would be seen as a block of code defining two
               // automatic variables scoped inside the block. Useless in this 
               // case.
    {
        string car_reg = 0; // this is actually NASTY! More on it later
        char car_manuf[30] = "EMPTY"; // assigns default value. But only if your 
                                      // compiler comes from this decade.
                                      // If you are rocking an antique you can't 
                                      // do this. Will cover what you can do  below.
        char car_model[30] = "EMPTY";

        string car_reg{}; // cannot reuse the car_reg identifier in the same scope
                          // car_reg is either a variable or a function.
    }; // ; goes here

    car c; // for testing purposes
    cout << c.car_manuf << ',' << c.car_model; // for testing
}
```

`string car_reg = 0;` is nasty. What it does is defines a member variable `car_reg` and uses 0 as the default. The 0 is converted to a null pointer to a `char` array. The `string` constructor attempts to initialize from a null pointer and blows up at runtime. The compiler is just fine with this bit of stupidity because in the old days `NULL` could be `#define NULL 0` and we don't want to break decades of old code by fixing this problem.

Since we can't do default initializations in pre C++11 code we need a constructor to do the work. Yup. `struct`s can have constructors. This is because a `struct` and a `class` are almost identical. The only difference you're ever likely to see between the two is `class` defaults to `private` access and `struct`s default to `public` access.

```cpp
struct car
{
    char car_manuf[30];
    char car_model[30];
    car (): car_manuf("EMPTY"), car_model("EMPTY")
    {

    }
};
```

Note that his isn't as groovy as it looks. You're usually better off with something like

```cpp
struct car
{
    string car_manuf;
    string car_model;
    car (const string & manuf,
         const string & model): car_manuf(manuf), car_model(model)
    {
        
    }
};
```

and not allowing the empty case at all. When possible force users to initialize a class into a fully initialized state. And use `std::string`. Very handy tool, `std::string`.

Note that

```cpp
struct car
{
    char car_manuf[30];
    char car_model[30];
    car (const char * manuf,
         const char * model): 
            car_manuf(manuf), car_model(model) // fails to compile
    {

    }
};
```

is not possible. You can't initialize a `char` array with a pointer to `char`. I'm not entirely certain why the language doesn't have a rule to handle this, but it doesn't. If forced to use `char` arrays,

```cpp
struct car
{
    char car_manuf[30];
    char car_model[30];
    car (const char * manuf,
         const char * model)
    {
        strcpy(car_manuf, manuf);
        strcpy(car_model, model);
    }
};
```

and make dang sure that `manuf` and `model` will fit in 29 characters or less.

Comment: Thannk you very well explained im still pretty new to this and trying to figure things out as lecturer isnt helpful at all...

Comment: A `string`'s default state, `string car_reg;`, is to provide an empty string. If you literally mean it contains the word `"Empty"`, `string car_reg = "Empty";`

Comment: Initialise the array of car registration structures by placing a “Empty” in the car registration
number of each array element

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a simple for loop, to fill (for example) the char_model array with zeros?

```
....

            char car_model[30];
            
            /* Adding the for loop here (it will fill car_model's elements with zeros*/
            for(int i=0; i<=sizeof(car_model); i++){
               car_model[i]=0;

....
```

Comment: Let me know if there is any problem; I had a bit trouble with the formatting again.

Comment: Tip: `memset()` or `bzero()` and not this.

Comment: And even if you decide to use a `for` loop, please don't obscure it like this, it makes it really hard to read

Comment: @UnholySheep I had to read this several times to see the side-effect in the middle.

Comment: Also when answering questions like this try and stay focused on your particular change, as in you could have just put in your new code. There's no need to repeat the rest of it.

Comment: @UnholySheep I'm sorry, one of my old habits. :P Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: hanks for help appreciate it.

Comment: @WilliamMartens getting this error as im trying to initialise car reg as empty   "Exception thrown at 0x796EFF80 (ucrtbased.dll) in Tester2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000."

Comment: Although that only happens when i run my code so ill keep going and see if issue continues

Comment: We have no idea what that DLL is.

Comment: @YassineJdair Okay, well - does it need to run as root?  +EDIT I forgot the = after the < arrow,  test the above snippet again. Sorry;  + Do you run it on Linux or Windows? (I assume Windows?)  Thanks for the info.

Comment: Im running it on windows.

Comment: i think issue is trying to declare car model its string car registration im trying to declare as empty -- chnaged it around but still getting erro no clue why

Comment: I do not know if this works(at all) but - worth a try, instead of the car_model - you can replace it with your car_reg, and instead of  =0; (in the for loop) you could ='\0'; to initialize it nulls. Now, Note that I (as stated) do not know if this works.

Comment: Still no luck god damn... thank you for help though

Comment: I will try to look what the problem is; but; hope it solves itself!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct car
    {
        string car_reg = {"Empty"};
        
        char car_manuf[30];
        char car_model[30];
        car(const char* manuf,
            const char* model)

        {
            strcpy(car_manuf, manuf);
            strcpy(car_model, model);
        }
    };
        
    
}
```

Comment: Recommendation: `string car_reg = {"Empty"};` could be `string car_reg{"Empty"};` or `string car_reg = "Empty";` Using both looks a bit weird. The compiler sorts it out, but humans are pretty bad compilers.